# Assert on all outputs - is that a good practice?

Tags: python, coding-style

**I am using assert on all outputs is that a good practice? also is this code clean and legible? Thank you!**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pyodbc
import secret as credentials

class DatabaseManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.database_user_name = credentials.Secret.mssql["database_username"]
        self.database_password = credentials.Secret.mssql["database_password"]
        self.database_server_name = credentials.Secret.mssql["database_server"]
        self.database_name = credentials.Secret.mssql["database_name"]
        self.database_string = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=' \
                               + self.database_server_name + ';DATABASE=' \
                               + self.database_name + ';UID=' \
                               + self.database_user_name + ';PWD=' \
                               + self.database_password \
                               + ';Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;'
        self.database_connection = pyodbc.connect(self.database_string)


class AccountManager:
    def __init__(self, account_email, account_name):
        self.account_email = account_email
        self.account_name = account_name

    def get_account_by_email(self):
        db_init = DatabaseManager()
        db_cursor = db_init.database_connection.cursor()
        db_cursor.execute("""  SELECT [account_email] FROM  [dbo].[account] 
                               WHERE account_email = ? """, self.account_email)
        row: object = db_cursor.fetchone()

        # verify and return
        assert isinstance(row, object)
        print(row)

    def get_account_by_name(self):
        db_init = DatabaseManager()
        db_cursor = db_init.database_connection.cursor()
        db_cursor.execute("""   SELECT [account_name] FROM  [dbo].[account] 
                                WHERE account_name = ? """, self.account_name)
        row: object = db_cursor.fetchone()

        # verify and return
        assert isinstance(row, object)
        print(row)


class ContractManager:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Comment: `isinstance(anything, object)` is always True, so your asserts are useless.

Comment: Also note that you aren't returning anything from thses functions. You're checking the type of an object that you're just printing out.

Comment: I am printing it out because I am testing it- It returns a value from the db. The values returned from the DB are str will include int.

Comment: For the second part of your question, is this code clean and legible, If you are looking for open-ended feedback on your code, you can post it on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `assert` statements on the instance of an object is generally not good in your case as it is always `True`.

The `assert` is quite useful to check on the `data-type` of the `inputs`.

example:

```
def add_num(num1):
    assert isinstance(num1, int), "the num1 should be of type 'int'."
    return num1+3
```

Or the code can be made better when you use the `type-hint` to the respective `arguments` you pass into the `object` of the `class`.

example:

```
def add_num(num1: int):
    return num1+3
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question.

Comment: but I can also do:  row: object = db_cursor.fetchone() then assert isinstance(row, object) to check the return type is what I expect? right? object, str, int, etc.

Comment: Yes, provided you are not sure of the type you are fetching from the DB, and I would also recommend using the message part to notify the user in case the assert rises.  i.e. assert <condition>, <message>

Comment: Thanks, Danke, Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, everything is an object. The assert statement you have will catch booleans, integers, lists, everything.

[image]

You said that sometimes an integer is returned from the database. If this is a problem, you should raise an error instead of using an assert statement.

Asserts should be used as a quick test performed on the spot to verify everything matches your expectations for what the data can look like before proceeding any further. Remember that assert statements are disabled in production mode. You want to only use them to verify conditions you believe have no way of ever being true, but just as a quick sanity check that can put your mind at ease, you put in the check anyways. If there is some way that the condition could be true, you should be using using an exception instead, so that an actual error is raised in production environments.

Also, be aware that [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) can cover a lot of things assert statements used to be used for.